# Defining own exception class in C++

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I tried to figure out how to implement my own base class for C++ exceptions which allow adding an error specific text string. I see no possibility for the std::c++ exceptions to change the error text, even not in C++11: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/.
I also want to derive more specific exceptions from my Exception-base class. I read a lot of articles but I am still unsure whether my following implementation covers all important aspects.

```
class Exception : public std::exception {      
    public:
        Exception(const char* message) : m(message) {

        }

        virtual ~Exception() throw() {

        }

        virtual const char* what() const throw() {
            return m.c_str();
        }

    protected:
        std::string m;

    private:
        Exception();
    };
```

Is this implementation fine?

Comment: what problem you see? should be posted in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error

Comment: Note alternatively, you may provide a `std::string` to `std::runtime_error`.

Answer (score 3):

If you derive from `runtime_error` (and your compiler supports inheriting constructors) you can condense your class to

```
struct Exception : public std::runtime_error
{
  using runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
```

`throw()`: Exception specifications are deprecated as of C++11, use `noexcept` instead.

Comment: And what if you want to throw a `logic_error` from time to time?

Comment: My point is, for a generic Exception base class like requested by the question, it seems odd to suggest deriving from `std::runtime_error`, which only represents a small subset of the possible error cases. This could complicate writing reasonable `catch` statements on the user side later.